# Wildfly not starting in debug mode with weld deployment stuck, but run mode is normal

Tags: deployment, wildfly, jboss-weld

When starting Wildfly 19 with Eclipse in run mode, it deploys and starts without problems.

When I'm starting it with debug mode, it starts then stops, still in the deployment phase.
This is how the log always ends:

```
2022-01-04 20:34:54,531 INFO  [be2aq664] [MSC service thread 1-3:] [org.jboss.weld.deployer] WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment com.xxx.jee.plugins.jar
2022-01-04 20:34:54,581 INFO  [be2aq664] [MSC service thread 1-2:] [org.jboss.weld.deployer] WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment com.xxx.jee.reporting.web.war
2022-01-04 20:34:54,583 INFO  [be2aq664] [MSC service thread 1-8:] [org.jboss.weld.deployer] WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment com.xxx.jee.services.facade.jar
2022-01-04 20:34:54,680 INFO  [be2aq664] [MSC service thread 1-8:] [org.jboss.weld.deployer] WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment com.xxx.jee.pvmt.web.war
2022-01-04 20:34:54,763 INFO  [be2aq664] [MSC service thread 1-4:] [org.jboss.weld.deployer] WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment com.xxx.jee.business.jar
2022-01-04 20:34:54,798 INFO  [be2aq664] [MSC service thread 1-1:] [org.jboss.weld.deployer] WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment com.xxx.jee.importer.jar
2022-01-04 20:34:54,799 INFO  [be2aq664] [MSC service thread 1-4:] [org.jboss.weld.deployer] WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment com.xxx.jee.remoting.web.war
2022-01-04 20:34:54,816 INFO  [be2aq664] [MSC service thread 1-1:] [org.jboss.weld.deployer] WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment com.xxx.jee.plugins.tmd.jar
2022-01-04 20:34:54,937 INFO  [be2aq664] [MSC service thread 1-1:] [org.jboss.weld.deployer] WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment com.xxx.jee.exporter.jar
2022-01-04 20:35:05,007 INFO  [be2aq664] [MSC service thread 1-6:] [io.jaegertracing.internal.JaegerTracer] No shutdown hook registered: Please call close() manually on application shutdown.
2022-01-04 20:35:04,984 INFO  [be2aq664] [MSC service thread 1-5:] [io.jaegertracing.internal.JaegerTracer] No shutdown hook registered: Please call close() manually on application shutdown.
2022-01-04 20:35:05,151 INFO  [be2aq664] [MSC service thread 1-2:] [io.jaegertracing.internal.JaegerTracer] No shutdown hook registered: Please call close() manually on application shutdown.
2022-01-04 20:36:15,801 INFO  [be2aq664] [MSC service thread 1-1:] [org.jboss.weld.deployer] WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment com.xxx.jee.utils.jar
2022-01-04 20:36:40,168 INFO  [be2aq664] [MSC service thread 1-6:] [org.jboss.weld.deployer] WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment com.xxx.jee.services.web.war
```

Then the log ends as the server shuts down. Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 0):

The "Skip All Breakpoints" in eclipse was disabled. As soon as I set it to skip all breakpoints it was resolved.